# How to activate bootstrap datepicker in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a script that apppend a row into a table. Each row has two datepicker textboxes for `start_date` and `end_date`.

```
var rows = "";
$("#btn_add").on('click', function(i){
    var ct_row  = $("#t_activity tr").not('.header').length+1;

    rows     = "<td class='text-center'><div class='date_set date_2'>";
        rows    += "<input type='text' class='form-control date dt_set' placeholder='start' onCopy='return false'";
        rows    += "  onDrag='return false' onDrop='return false' onPaste='return false' onkeypress='return false' />";
    rows    += "</div></td>";

    rows    += "<td><div class='date_end date_2'>";
        rows    += "<input type='text' class='form-control date dt_end' placeholder='Finish' onCopy='return false'";
        rows    += "  onDrag='return false' onDrop='return false' onPaste='return false' onkeypress='return false' />";
    rows    += "</div></td>";

    $("#t_activity").append("<tr class='tr_content'>"+rows+"</tr>");
});
```

If I put the `datepicker` script inside the `button click event after the append`, it's working but I need to process the `datepicker` outside the `button event`. This is the `datepicker` script:

```
//START
    $('.date_set .date').datepicker({
        startView           : 0,   
        forceParse          : true,
        autoclose           : true,
        format              : "dd/mm/yyyy",
        todayHighlight      : true,
    }).on('changeDate', function(selected){
        var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        $('.date_end .date').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
    }); 

    $('.date_end .date').datepicker({
        startView           : 0,
        todayBtn            : "linked",
        forceParse          : true,
        autoclose           : true,     
        format              : "dd/mm/yyyy",
        todayHighlight      : true,
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        $('.date_set .date').datepicker('setEndDate', selected.date);
    }); 
//END
```

I've tried changing the script like this but the it's failed to show the `datepicker`:

```
$("#t_activity tbody").on('click','.date_set .date',function(){ 
    $(this).closest('tr').find('div .dt_set').datepicker({
        startView           : 0,   
        forceParse          : true,
        autoclose           : true,
        format              : "dd/mm/yyyy",
        todayHighlight      : true,
        }).on('changeDate', function(selected){
            var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
            $('.date_end .date').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what you need to declare as a `datepicker` is the input itself. So, in the first case, it would be class `dt_set` rather than `date_set`.

Second, when using the delegate method, you could use `focus` event, rather than `click` event

```
$('#t_activity').on('focus',".dt_set", function(){
});
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/zw4a8pfv/

Or, if you are using `tbody` in your `table` you could also declare it as bellow

```
$('#t_activity tbody').on('focus',".dt_set", function(){
});
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/zw4a8pfv/1/

Comment: woah thx. `focus` is better than `click` in my problem. One more, do you know how to set up `2nd row start textbox startdate = 1st finish textbox value`, `3rd row start textbox startdate = 2nd finish textbox value` and so on?

Comment: @Vahn your welcome. That would be a different question, you should Ask another question for that.